# Outlook Not Getting E-mail Unless Restarted

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, exchange

My iPhone and iPad are connected to my Exchange server, and right after an e-mail is sent, both of them light up and receive it.

I also run Outlook 2010 (connected to the same Exchange server), and starting a few days ago it stopped receiving e-mail right after it is sent. Sometimes it will come in 10 minutes late, other times, it won't come in until I restart Outlook. All the e-mail will come in when I restart Outlook.

Any thoughts on what's going on?

Update 1: Here's an image of my connection status:

[image]

Comment: Does it (Outlook client) ever get disconnected from the Exchange server?  Do you have trouble sending and receiving or just receiving?  What is the connectivity output of doing a ctrl + right click -> Connection Status on the Outlook icon in the system tray?

Comment: @jmreicha I attached an image of my connection status - if I press reconnect, all of the mail comes in.

Comment: Does going to File->Options->Advanced, then click Send and Receive and put a check next to Schedule an automatic send/receive every 5 minutes help at all?

Comment: I don't think that I have enough information but I suspect that your connection is being reset somehow.  Do other users have this same problem?  How often does it happen?  When did it start happening?

Comment: I have the same issue

Comment: Can you get a pcap of the issue? Outlook may be having issues communicating with the exchange server. In any case, finding out what is going on while outlook is unable to retrieve mail will be the most useful piece of information you can get.

Comment: I would also look into your network connection. Are you connected by wire or wireless?

Comment: Having the same issue with one of my users.  Problem is definitely local to the machine though because I was able to get it to update without any issues on another device.  I will followup with steps I took if I find a way to get it working.

Answer (score 2):

Repair the `OST` file. Sometimes the `OST` file becomes corrupt, go to `Program Files\Microsoft Office\OFFICE12` and run `Scanpst.exe`.

Comment: This would be more likely if it just stopped being able to write to or read from the PST altogether, but if just restarting outlook makes it work for a while again, then it is more likely something else. In these cases a pcap of the traffic is a better bet than just shooting at random solutions rarely works well.

Answer (score 2):

I was having a similar issue as this and found a solution I figured I would share here.

**Summary**

In my case, the user has access to multiple mailboxes and was caching all of them.  Which seemed to cause problems with immediate updates while the user was using Outlook.

**What I did**

1. I went into my user's account settings to `Change`

[image]

2. Opened up `More Settings`

[image]

3. Then went to the `Advanced` tab and unchecked `Download shared folder` under the **Cached Exchange Mode Settings**

[image]

This fixed my problem, although I am not sure if this fix is applicable to everyone.

**Bear in mind**

`Cached Exchange Mode` stores a local *cache* of your outlook files and folders on your local machine in an `.ost` file.  This allows for users to use and manipulate their emails even when offline.

Turning this feature off, while it may fix the problem, will prevent users from viewing or using their email while offline.  While the `Download shared folders` options will only do it for the extra mailboxes the user is given permission to in Exchange.

**Extra:** Shortening the amount of time it caches could also help.

Answer (score 0):

Check the Send/Receive settings. I'm not at a computer now, so I don't remember the exact steps. Don't set the Send/Receive frequency to less than 15 minutes, it can cause you to get blocked out of the server, depending on server settings.

Also, you can always press F9 to trigger the general Send/Receive.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Outlook 2010. Somewhere along the line Microsoft updates broke the email notification banner (using Windows7). I found a tip on creating a rule to display a banner when emails are received. Turned out after much time trying to troubleshoot, the rule I created to notify me with an alert that I've received email was causing Outlook to randomly stop receiving new emails. I'd rather get my emails and only be notified by the little envelope in the task/status bar than to have to restart Outlook several times a day. I removed the rule and all is well.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly overlooked solution - simpler than anything.
I was having no luck on this same issue with days of combing the internet, repairing, reinstalling, etc. I thought Outlook 2016 might be just getting old or something.
But it still worked fine on my laptop running same OS, so why not on my PC? Finally I found something basic I overlooked. In File > Account Settings > Server Settings I noticed that for one of my accounts I had a merely "workable" address for the Server address. ["mail.mydomain.com" vs something more specific from the host like  "xxxx1234.hostingservice.com"] I should stress that a tech at the hosting service had me change it to mail.mydomain.com a while back, saying it was all the same. NOT.
Once I switched it, it has been smooth sailing.
I hope this is your easy solution as well.